# How to set background color for grid columns based on cell values in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, styles, converters

I need to set the background for cells based on cell text values. For a single column, I need to show multiple backgrounds based on values. I am dynamically loading the values.

cell 1 - Value 1 - Red

Cell 2 - Value 2-  green

Cell 3 - Value 1- Red.

Above cells are in the same column. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use an **IValueConverter** that converts your actual value to a certain color.

In code behind:

```
public class ValueToBgColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // logic here, and return a color, like
        return Brushes.Black;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And in XAML:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=Value,Converter={StaticResource ValueToBgColorCoverter}}"/>
    </Style>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
```

Comment: You mentioned here to bind one property to set the background. But my question is to get the value from that cell and set background based on that value. 
     DataMemberBinding="{Binding SubStatus}"

Comment: I just gave an example, you need to adjust the binding with the converter to bind to the property that is the source of the cell value.